# How can I insert html embed code to react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, widget, embed

I got the embed code from tradingview below.

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/markets/currencies/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Forex</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async>
  {
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "dateRange": "12M",
  "showChart": false,
  "locale": "en",
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "largeChartUrl": "",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "showFloatingTooltip": false,
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "Forex",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "FX:EURUSD",
          "d": "EUR/USD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCAD",
          "d": "USD/CAD"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Forex"
    }
  ]
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

And When I copy and paste to the react

```
const TestPage = () => {
<>
<div>
// Here I want to insert that embed widget
</div>
</>
};
export default TestPage;
```

Then the red line error with " It need '}' "  and "Unexpected Token. do you mean '{'{'}' or &rbrace"

There's exactly a couple of { and } but Why is it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use npm 'react-ts-tradingview-widgets'

Answer (score 1):

Brackets have a different meaning in React, so the object defined inside your `<script>` tag cannot be parsed.
Technically you could use backticks to correctly add this object, like the following code. You could also add the object in the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` prop of your `<script>` tag.

However, I tested your snippet in a React project, event in a blank HTML page, and it doesn't seem to display any chart, so tell me if your problemed is solved, otherwise maybe you should use a lib like [react-trading-widget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tradingview-widget)

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async>
  {`{
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "dateRange": "12M",
  "showChart": false,
  "locale": "en",
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "largeChartUrl": "",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "showFloatingTooltip": false,
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "Forex",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "FX:EURUSD",
          "d": "EUR/USD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCAD",
          "d": "USD/CAD"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Forex"
    }
  ]
}`}
  </script>
```

Comment: [widgetprovider](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/) I use this embed code, and when I use your methon '{}', it didn't work.  I have to find out somehow. Thanks for the answer! :)